# How to compare two table values using PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have to compare two tables values;

```
TABLE_A     TABLE_B 

ID  TYPE    ID  TYPE
12345       12345   3
67891       12345   7
36524       67891   3
            67891   2
            67891   5
            36524   3
```

Logic: I have to compare table_A id with Table_B id

if found 3&7 
         good
else found 3 only
         avg
else if found 7 only
         bad

These good, bad and avg should go back to table A type values.

could any one help me how to write this code in PLSQL.

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: What about values of TYPE which are neither 3 nor 7?  How do they affect the outcome?

Comment: If neither 3 nor 7 then type column should get "NULL". Store procedure is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are considering type 3 and 7 only for your calculations, you can use following merge statement, no need of PL-SQL

```
merge into table_a a
using (select id, case (listagg(type, ',') within group (order by type))
                    when '3,7' then 'Good'
                    when '3'   then 'Avg'
                    when '7'   then 'Bad'
                    else null
                  end new_type
         from table_b
        where type in (3,7)
       group by id) b
   on (a.id = b.id)
 when matched then
   update set type = new_type;
```

For Oracle versions prior to 11 g release 2, use following:

```
merge into table_a a
using (select id, case (trim(both ',' from min(decode(type, 3, 3, null))||','||min(decode(type, 7, 7, null))))
                when '3,7' then 'Good'
                when '3'   then 'Avg'
                when '7'   then 'Bad'
                else null
              end new_type
     from table_b
    where type in (3,7)
   group by id) b
   on (a.id = b.id)
 when matched then
   update set type = new_type;
```

It has been assumed that there are unique combination of id an type in table_b.

Comment: Its giving error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Which version of Oracle you are using? Use `select * from v$version` to know.

Comment: Hi, I am using Oracle 11g release 1. i guess its not supporting LISTAGG. Any other solution for this question?

Comment: @Qasim0788 I have modified the post for Oracle 11g release 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting what you mean as saying that you want to output `'good'` when `TableB` contains both 3 and 7, `'avg'` when it contains only 3, and so on.  Here is a way to get this result:

```
select a.id,
       (case when sum(case when b.type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 1 and
                  sum(case when b.type = 7 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'good'
             when sum(case when b.type = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 1
             then 'avg'
             when sum(case when b.type = 7 then 1 else 0 end)
             then 'bad'
        end) as logic
from tableA a left outer join
     tableB b
     on a.id = b.id
group by a.id;
```